# Update room db android with static variables

Tags: android, sql, android-room, dao

I can't find a way to use my static variables inside the DAO method, without passing them through the method itself.

example:

This works:

```
@Transaction
@Query("UPDATE OpsPrinterDevice SET connectionStatus=:from WHERE connectionStatus=:to")
abstract fun switchDevicesConnection(from: String = Parameters.CONNECTED,to: String = Parameters.DISCONNECTED)
```

This does not work:

```
@Transaction
@Query("UPDATE OpsPrinterDevice SET connectionStatus=${Parameters.CONNECTED} WHERE connectionStatus=${Parameters.DISCONNECTED}")
abstract fun switchDevicesConnection()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the latter does not work is due to the [SQLite syntax for literal values](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_). You need to enclose a string value in single quotes e.g.

```
@Query("UPDATE OpsPrinterDevice SET connectionStatus='${Parameters.CONNECTED}' WHERE connectionStatus='${Parameters.DISCONNECTED}'")
```

- *However, it is recommended that embedding variables, as opposed to binding them, is not used. Bound values (aka using `:passed_variable`) are automatically correctly enclosed and afforded protection against SQL Injection.*